# Getting fatal: Dirty repository: Having uncommitted changes. Exiting... in Pipelines with git ftp push

Tags: git, bitbucket-pipelines, git-ftp

I have a Pipelines setup with automatic processing/building of CSS files. Some of the time I get this error when doing `git ftp push`:

> fatal: Dirty repository: Having uncommitted changes. Exiting...

**bitbucket-pipelines.yml**

```
image: php:7.2.7

pipelines:
 branches:
   staging:
     - step:
         name: Deploy to staging
         deployment: staging
         script:
           - curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash -
           - apt-get install -y nodejs
           - npm install
           - npm run build-css
           - apt-get update
           - apt-get -qq install git-ftp
           - git status -uno --porcelain
           - git ftp push --user $FTP_username --passwd $FTP_password ftp://ftp.website.com
```

**Output from** `git status -uno --porcelain`

```
git status -uno --porcelain
 M style.css
```

In the past I have committed style.css (what is now getting built automatically)-- but now want it to ignore my local style.css file as it is getting generated during the build anyways. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's too late but today I faced the same problem. After some research I deleted `yarn.lock` file from the repo and the problem disappear. Hope that helps!